# Why does PowerShell's Get-Content return "cannot be read/access denied" when cmd's type works for same file?

Tags: powershell

I employ a user-defined function, called searchfor, from a PowerShell console prompt (Run as Administrator) to find files containing strings:

```
PS repo> gc Function:\searchfor

param([string]$root, [string[]]$includeexpression, [string]$regexp)

$fullpath = convert-path $root
Get-ChildItem -force -recurse $fullpath -include $includeexpression | Select-String $regexp
```

This has recently started to fail on some files with the following "cannot be read/access denied" error message:

```
Select-String : The file C:\builds\repo\LightweightSerialization\LightweightSerializationWriter.cs cannot be read: Access to the path 'C:\builds\repo\LightweightSerialization\LightweightSerializationWriter.cs' is denied.
At C:\Users\schlagermeier\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1:174 char:71
+ ... recurse $fullpath -include $includeexpression | Select-String $regexp
+                                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Select-String], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ProcessingFile,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SelectStringCommand
```

An attempt to read the file interactively with Get-Content fails with the same error.  However, if I launch a Command Prompt (cmd.exe), also using Run as Administrator, I can read the file content with the type command.

I've looked at the file's permissions and acl, and it doesn't appear any different to others in the same folder which can be read by PowerShell.  Can anybody suggest any possible causes and how these might be identified and fixed?

Comment: the error you show is NOT from `Get-Content`. it's from `Select-String` ...

Comment: It would be helpful to include the acls in the question (e.g. using icacls). Also, you can use `[System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()` to see which user you're actually running as, and if it's really with admin privileges.